# Ruby on rails complex dynamic forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have implemented rails complex form from Railscasts tutorial in my Rails app.
I want to add ajax inside the complex form, where in I have implemented a prefill functionality inside the complex form. But I need to know the unique id of the div the complex form generates automatically.

```
<div class="inputs">
  <span class="input_wrapper">
    <input class="text" id="formname_attributes_0_example" name="formname[attributes]  [0][example]" size="30" type="text" />
  </span>
  <button  type="button" onclick="dinfill(this);" >Pre-fill</button>      
</div>
<div class="inputs">
  <span class="input_wrapper">
   <input class="text" id="formname_attributes_1_example" name="formname[attributes]  [1][example]" size="30" type="text" />
  </span>
  <button  type="button" onclick="dinfill(this);" >Pre-fill</button>          
</div>
```

How do I fetch `id="formname_attributes_1_example"` the unique id '1' or any id from the above code.

Comment: Once you have finalized the form that you want to use, you can take a look at the id's of whatever element you like in the source code. Is there a reason you don't want to do this?